# .transform / .compose duplicates Mono execution with Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor

While implementing an authentication solution based on Spring Security Reactive, I faced an issue where the operations in the chain get duplicated at some point. From that, everything was called twice.

The culprit was the operator `.transform` at one point of the chain. After editing the called method and replacing the operator by `.flatMap`, the issue was resolved and everything was only called once.

### The question

According to the [operator's documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/index.html#_using_the_transform_operator), the

> function is applied to an original operator chain at assembly time to augment it with the encapsulated operators

and

> is basically equivalent to chaining the operators directly.

**Why did the operator `.transform` trigger a second subscription to the chain, then ?**

### The context

This authentication flow takes a trusted username and retrieves its details from a webservice.

The authentication method to implement the `ReactiveAuthenticationManager` :

```java
@Override
public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication providedAuthentication) {
    String username = (String) providedAuthentication.getPrincipal();
    String token = (String) providedAuthentication.getCredentials();

    return Mono.just(providedAuthentication)
            .doOnNext(x -> LOGGER.debug("Starting authentication of user {}", x))
            .doOnNext(AuthenticationValidator.validateProvided)
            .then(ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext())
            .map(SecurityContext::getAuthentication)
            .flatMap(auth -> AuthenticationValidator.validateCoherence(auth, providedAuthentication))
            .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> {
                LOGGER.trace("Switch if empty before retrieving user");
                return retrieveUser(username, token);
            }))
            .doOnNext(logAccess);
}
```

The duplication of the calls started from the supplier of `.switchIfEmpty` until the end of the chain.

---

The method creating the `Mono` used by `.switchIfEmpty` :

```java
private Mono<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> retrieveUser(String username, String token) {
    return  Mono.just(username)
            .doOnNext(x -> LOGGER.trace("Before find by username"))
            .then(habileUserDetails.findByUsername(username, token))
            .cast(XXXUserDetails.class)
            .transform(rolesProvider::provideFor)
            .map(user -> new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user, GlobalConfiguration.NO_CREDENTIAL, user.getAuthorities()))
            .doOnNext(s -> LOGGER.debug("User data retrieved from XXX"));
}
```

The operator `.transform` on line 4 has been replaced by `.flatMap` to resolve the issue.

---

The original method called by the `.transform` operator :

```java
public Mono<CompleteXXXUserDetails> provideFor(Mono<XXXUserDetails> user) {
    return user
        .map(XXXUserDetails::getAuthorities)
        .map(l -> StreamHelper.transform(l, GrantedAuthority::getAuthority))
        .map(matcher::match)
        .map(enricher::enrich)
        .map(l -> StreamHelper.transform(l, SimpleGrantedAuthority::new))
        .zipWith(user, (authorities, userDetails)
            -> CompleteXXXUserDetails.from(userDetails).withAllAuthorities(authorities));
}
```

---

Here is a trace of the execution :

```java
DEBUG 20732 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.s.s.h.a.XXXAuthenticationManager  : Starting authentication of user [REDACTED]
TRACE 20732 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.s.s.h.a.XXXAuthenticationManager  : Switch if empty before retrieving user
TRACE 20732 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.s.s.h.a.XXXAuthenticationManager  : Before find by username
TRACE 20732 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.s.s.xxx.user.UserRetriever        : Between request and call
TRACE 20732 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.s.s.h.u.retriever.UserRetrieverV01: Calling webservice v01
TRACE 20732 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.s.s.h.a.XXXAuthenticationManager  : Before find by username
TRACE 20732 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.s.s.xxx.user.UserRetriever        : Between request and call
TRACE 20732 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] c.a.s.s.h.u.retriever.UserRetrieverV01: Calling webservice v01
```

For information, I'm using Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer doesn't address the root cause** but rather explains how a `transform` could be applied several times when subscribed to several times, which is not the case in OP's issue. Edited the original text into a quote.

> That statement is only valid when the `transform` is applied as a top-level operator in the chain you subscribe to. Here you are applying it within `retrieveUser`, **which is invoked inside a `Mono.defer`** (which goal is to execute that code for each different subscription).
>   (edit:) so if that `defer` is subscribed to x times, the transform `Function` will be applied x times as well.
>
> `compose` is basically `transform`-inside-a-`defer` by the way.

Comment: Thanks Simon. With that in mind, is there a way to have the expected behavior of `.transform` at other levels ? I get that `.defer`'s instructions are executed at each subscription, but why is there a duplicated subscription in the first place ? Because of `.transform`'s *unexpected* behavior ?

Comment: `transform` doesn't cause a subscription, so it must come from somewhere else... if you look at the source, `flux.transform(function)` is just `function.apply(flux)`. maybe in that light you can find why applying `provideFor` function would result in "extra subscriptions". btw can you show how you became aware of these extra subscriptions?

Comment: If you look at the trace of execution I provided, you can see that the last 6 lines are duplicated. In the first code extract, you can see the log line that corresponds to the second line of the trace of execution. What really bugs me, is that the log instruction that's also is in the `.defer` is executed only once, while what's after is executed twice.

Comment: can you also share what the original `provideFor` used to look like?

Comment: That's the original one, before I fixed the issue. I'm editing the question to be clearer.

Comment: the real issue lies somewhere else, added an answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the fact that you do a `user.whatever(...).zipWith(user, ...)`.

With transform, this translates to:

```
Mono<XXXUserDetails> user = Mono.just(username)
    .doOnNext(x -> LOGGER.trace("Before find by username"))
    .then(habileUserDetails.findByUsername(username, token))
    .cast(XXXUserDetails.class);

return user.wathewer(...)
    .zipWith(user, ...);
```

Whereas with flatMap I assume you did something to the effect of `flatMap(u -> provideFor(Mono.just(u))`? If so, that would translate to:

```
Mono<XXXUserDetails> user = Mono.just(username)
    .doOnNext(x -> LOGGER.trace("Before find by username"))
    .then(habileUserDetails.findByUsername(username, token))
    .cast(XXXUserDetails.class);

return user.flatMap(u -> {
    Mono<XXXUserDetails> capture = Mono.just(u);
    return capture.whatever(...)
        .zipWith(capture, ...);
}
```

You can see how both subscribe twice to *a* `Mono<XXXUserDetails` due to `zipWith`.

The reason is *seems* to subscribe once with `flatMap` is because it captures the output of the upstream pipeline and applies the `provideFor` function on that capture. The capture (`Mono.just(u)`) is subscribed twice but acts as a cache and doesn't bear any logic / logs / etc...

With `transform`, there is no capture. The `provideFor` function is applied directly to the upstream pipeline, which makes the fact that it subscribes twice quite visible.